# How can I get the name of a class in C++ using a file with my code?

Tags: c++, string, file, data-structures

For example:

class LOC_COUNTER //b
{
     ...
}

I just want to get "LOC COUNTER", in the context of the file that I got with I/O reader I have a String with "class LOC_COUNTER //b" but I just want the name of the class.

Comment: What's `//b`?​​ What file? What I/O reader? Are you trying to parse C++ source? Too vague.

Answer (score 3):

You can use typeid:

```
class X
{
    int a;
};

int main()
{

    X myVariable;
    cout << typeid(myVariable).name() << endl;

}
```

This prints an IMPLEMENTATION DEFINED string.  In Visual Studio 2015, it prints "class X".

Comment: And in some implementations that I've seen (can't remember which) you just get an empty string, sadly. So it's completely unreliable... not to mention that RTTI isn't always even available. However, for non-crucial applications or applications on specific platforms, it's your best and only bet unless you wanna start hardcoding stuff.

Comment: Also it looks like the OP is actually trying to parse C++, not obtain reflection information about the currently executing program. Though the question is far from clear.

Comment: Yeah, maybe, it wasn't clear.  That's why I put a code sample in the answer.

Comment: Mmm sorry for ambiguity. What I'm trying to say is that I have the string line = "class MyNewClass" The question is: How can I get only "My NewClass"